# Advanced count with join SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, items & categories, sample data below:

```
Items:
Title    category_id
Item A   1
Item B   2
Item C   3
Item D   2
Item E   3
Item F   2

Categories
category_id   category
1             wood
2             plastic
3             metal
```

What I need to do is to count the total number of items, then list how many are in each category and what % that is of the total

I know I can count each item and total e.g.

```
select 
  count(*) as total, 
  sum(category_id=1) as cat_1, 
  sum(category_id=2
.... etc etc
```

But is there a way to do it all without counting each (there maybe new categories added and would like this to stay working) and then joining with categories table to produce the name?

Ideally this is what I'd like to return:

```
Category    how many    % of total
wood        1           17%
plastic     3           50%
metal       2           33%

Total       6           100%
```

(17% is 1/6th => 16.666666667% rounded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select ifnull(c.category, 'TOTAL') as Category, 
    count(i.category_id) AS `how many`, 
    round(count(i.category_id) / (select count(*) from Items) * 100) as `% of total`
from Categories c
left outer join Items i on c.category_id = i.category_id
where c.category is not null
group by c.category
with rollup
```

Note, this will also correctly handle empty categories.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cc84/9)

**Output:**

```
| CATEGORY | HOW MANY | % OF TOTAL |
------------------------------------
|    glass |        0 |          0 |
|    metal |        2 |         33 |
|  plastic |        3 |         50 |
|     wood |        1 |         17 |
|    TOTAL |        6 |        100 |
```

Comment: I don't often use this method of counting because it doesn't handle "0 items" very well.  For example, try adding a category:  `(4, 'other')`

Comment: @Tim see example above, handles it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

here this is initial start for you. this will give you first and second column. to get 3 column you will have do some calculation.

```
select c.Category, Count(Category_id)
from dbo.Items i
INNER JOIN dbo.Categories c
    ON i.Category_Id = c.Category_ID
GROUP BY c.Category
```

Answer (score 0):

This cross-join style of counting will account for categories that have zero items:

```
select c.Category
    , (select count(*) from Items where category_id = c.category_id) as HowMany
    , (select count(*) from Items where category_id = c.category_id)
        / (select count(*) from Items) * 100
        as PctOfTotal
from Categories as c;
```